# How to Detect incoming call in background mode in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

So please help me I am using this code

```
    self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    [self.callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call)
     {
          if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
         {

         }
     }];
```

Comment: u checked the code?

Answer (score 0):

**u can check .... :**

```
-(void)callStatusChecking{
    if (ctCallCenter.currentCalls == nil)
    {
        // do ur code...
        }
    }else{
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(callStatusChecking)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

u can call this method when ur app went in background mode... where u want it .